# Why my generalized term does not give the correct answer

Tags: binomial-theorem

If in the expansion of $(1+x)^m (1-x)^n$, the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ are $3$ and $-6$ respectively, then $m$ is

My try:
$(1+x)^m (1-x)^n= (m,r)x^r\cdot(n,t)(-x^t)= (m,r)(n,t)(-1)^tx^{r+t}$
Putting $r+t=1$ we get $(m,r)(n,t)(-1)^t=3$. Now $t$ must be equal to $0$,so $r=1$. Therefore, $(m,1)(n,0)=3$ or $m=3$.
But the answer given is $12$.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The formula for the product is not correct. You are missing some sums.

Answer (score 2):

By binomial theorem,
$$(1+x)^m=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m}{k}x^k$$
$$(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}(-x)^k$$
Using convolutions, the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^m(1-x)^n$ is
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{m}{k-i}\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i$$

So, the coefficient of $x^1$ and $x^2$ are respectively
$$\binom{m}{1}-\binom{n}{1}=m-n$$
$$\binom{m}{2}-\binom{m}{1}\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}=\frac{m^2+n^2-2mn-m-n}{2}$$
Since we are given that the coefficient of $x^1$ is $3$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-6$, we have the following system
$$\begin{cases} m-n=3\\m^2+n^2-2mn-m-n=-12\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} m-n=3\\(m-n)^2-m-n=-12\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} m-n=3\\9-m-n=-12\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} m-n=3\\m+n=21\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} \boxed{m=12}\\n=9\end{cases}$$